# FubuMVC: How to I create a zero-model out action on my controller?

Tags: attributes, controller, action, void, fubumvc

In FubuMVC, when I want a controller action method to return a json result, I use the JsonEndpoint attribute on the method.  However there is not a corresponding attribute for a void method that I can see.

For a particular action, I don't want to return anything, but if I have a void return result Fubu fails because it starts looking for a view to match an empty model to.

Is there a attribute or easy change to allow a particular action method to return void?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I updated to a newer version of the framework, one-model-in, zero-model-out controller actions became instantly usable.  The only thing I'm not sure how to do is controller-less views.